# Download issue in php

Tags: php, download

I have a php script for downloading mp4 videp files . It is working properly now for files having small size (upto 60 MB is tested) . When i try for a big one (300 MB) it displays an error related with "memory limit" . So that done some edits in ini file for increasing the memory limit upto 400 MB (memory_limit = 400M) . Then i try to run my script , But the download box is displaying a content size of 189 bytes. I tried it with an another mp4 file (small size) , its working well . I dont understand the reason for it . So please kindly direct me . My script is as follows..

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder_name/filename.mp4";
$filesize = filesize($file);
$fileName=$file;
$offset = 0;
$length = $filesize;

if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) ) {

    $partialContent = true;

    preg_match('/bytes=(\d+)-?/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches);

    $offset = intval($matches[1]);
    $length = $filesize - $offset;
}else {
    $partialContent = false;
}

$file = fopen($file, 'r');

fseek($file, $offset);

$data = fread($file, $length);

fclose($file);

if ( $partialContent ) {

    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');

    header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $offset . '-' . ($offset + $length) . '/' . $filesize);
}

header("Content-type: video/mp4");
header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
print($data);
```

The download box displaying is..

[image]

Comment: if it is showing a content size of 189 bytes the script probably errored out and the contents of that file will probably be the text of that error, open up the file in a text editor and see.

Comment: try ` ini_set('memory_limit', '300M'); ` however, if you don't have to do any kind of validations, why don't you place the mp4 files on a directory and let users directly download from server?

Comment: @ Patrick Evans : Thanks alot. As you said there was an error of "allowed memory size of *** bytes exhausted".so that i added a line of code in my script (ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')). Now the pblm is solved..Thanks alot.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Please check with your server sometime your server not support this many memory allocation to your script.

Please add following line on top of script.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
```

then let me know if that not working.

Comment: no good. PHP by default uses these directives to prevent over-use of memory. Do not remove those limits or server will be very memory consuming.

Answer (score -2):

It isnt good to change all directives without a good reason, so the first step is to know what specific problem you have.

When you run a script for downloading files, like in this case, mp4 video files, and the download box is displaying a content size much smaller than the actual file, its easy to get a clue about what was wrong:

You just need to download that file and, no matter it looks like a video, open it with a text editor.

**Right click > open with...** and then select any text editor.

You will find that the actual content of the file is the information about the error occurred in the server. With this you will have better information about what happened, so you can figure out for example, if it is related to the memory_limit, to the max_execution_time, or to any other reason.

Now you can decide to change one or more of the directives, or probably change your script to get a better performance.

Note: if the file you downloaded is empty, or doesnt contain any error information, probably you have the error reporting disabled. To enable it you can add this two lines at the begining of the script:

```
ini_set("display_errors","1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: You should clean up this answer, including word choice/sentence structure, and try to provide code examples where possible.

Comment: I'm not even sure what this answer really has to do with the question asked. Certainly it does not reflect a good grasp of the question or what has already been tried and seen.

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel, I'll try to improve my writing. 
Andrew, im sorry i explained it so bad that you dont even know if its related to the question. It is, let me edit it to explain what I tried to say. I'm new in stackoverflow and id like to be helpful so all this comments are wellcome.